# Is there a way to hardcode user inputs in a Dockerfile or run docker build in interactive mode?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using a Dockerfile to install a tool. I am running `docker build -f Dockerfile -t ubuntu:mytool .` command to initiate the build. The line `RUN ./toolPackageInstaller` expects two user inputs (1) install path selection and (2) an integer for timezone info halfway through the installation. How do I hardcode this info in a dockerfile or run `docker build` in interactive mode so the user can input these values during the install process?

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    sudo \
    git \
    make
COPY ToolPackage.tar.xz /tmp
RUN tar xvfJp /tmp/ToolPackage.tar.xz

WORKDIR /tmp/ToolPackage
RUN chmod +x toolPackageInstaller
RUN ./toolPackageInstaller
```

Answer (score 2):

Use build arguments for those desired arguments:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ARG ARGUMENT_1=<HARDCODED_VALUE>
ARG ARGUMENT_2=<HARDCODED_VALUE>

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    sudo \
    git \
    make
COPY ToolPackage.tar.xz /tmp
RUN tar xvfJp /tmp/ToolPackage.tar.xz

WORKDIR /tmp/ToolPackage
RUN chmod +x toolPackageInstaller
RUN ./toolPackageInstaller $ARGUMENT_1 $ARGUMENT_2
```

And configure the script on `toolPackageInstaller` to use those values as input (referring to them with `$1` and `$2`)

By default it will run with the hardcoded value, and also you can override it if you desire:

`docker build --build-arg ARGUMENT_1=<NEW_VALUE> --build-arg ARGUMENT_2=<ANOTHER_NEW_VALUE> -t ubuntu:mytool .`

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work. `./toolPackageInstaller` does not take any arguments. The docker build process is stuck midway waiting for user input. If there is no way to do this, does `docker build` command support interactive mode so the user can input the values?

Comment: No, `docker build` isn't interactive so any script that you run needs to be able to run unsupervised. If you really need to use it interactively because the package you need didn't implement better, you could use some "shell wizardry" as the `expect` package. Here you can check the `man` from the `expect` command: https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect